# Publish local plan as xy coordinates

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, local-planner, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I can obtain the /cmd_vel information for the local plan of robot to extract velocities and angles but is there usually a topic that I can subscribe to to obtain the local navigation goal in terms of coordinates?
Just this would be more ideal for the external flight controller.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323856/publish-local-plan-as-xy-coordinates/) by [jamesislost](https://answers.ros.org/users/38762/jamesislost/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might be able to find what you're looking for on the `local_plan` topic of the local planner plugin that you have configured ([docs](http://wiki.ros.org/base_local_planner#API_Stability)). Note that a local planner can (and will) change the plan many times as it's trying to execute the global plan as best as possible given the current state of the robot and the world.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jamesislost](https://answers.ros.org/users/38762/jamesislost/) on 2019-05-23**:
Thanks! @gvdhoorn quick and simple answer!